# how to toggle table rows from 3rd

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple tables on a page.
Each table has more than 10 rows.
The design is to show first rows on each table with a 'show more' button.
Once a user clicks the show more button.
It will expand the hidden rows on the clicked table only.

Any idea to make it easily?

It seems hard to implement by css, because there are multiple tables on a page.

My idea is to put the toogle button on each table.
Which will intercept the click trigger. And find the closest parent table.
Finally, change all the rows style in the table. from display:none to show.

Comment: can you show your code, this is important so we can figure out an advice or solution based on your implementation

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: I have edit my code as per your requirement please check it...

Comment: Have any of the answers below helped? Have we missed something? If so, please include some code for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've not given us much to go on, we will assume that your toggle buttons immediately follow your tables.

I've given you three options. **No Jquery**, **Jquery** and **CSS** with a bit of a hack.

**No Jquery**

```js
var toggleButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleTable");

for (var i = 0; i < toggleButtons.length; i++) {
  toggleButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('collapsed');
  }, false);
}
```

```css
/*Change nth-child as required*/

table.collapsed>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="collapsed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1 C1</td>
      <td>R1 C2</td>
      <td>R1 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2 C1</td>
      <td>R2 C2</td>
      <td>R2 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R3 C1</td>
      <td>R3 C2</td>
      <td>R3 C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Toggle Rows" class="toggleTable">
```

*Support Issues*, this will have issues in IE 9 and lower, other major browsers should be fine.:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling

http://caniuse.com/#search=classList

**Jquery** -- Solves the support issues above.

```js
$(".toggleTable").click(function(){
  $(this).prev("table").toggleClass("collapsed");  
});
```

```css
/*Change nth-child as required*/
table.collapsed>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2)
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="collapsed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
      </tr>      
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>R1 C1</td>
        <td>R1 C2</td>
        <td>R1 C3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2 C1</td>
        <td>R2 C2</td>
        <td>R2 C3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R3 C1</td>
        <td>R3 C2</td>
        <td>R3 C3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Toggle Rows" class="toggleTable">
```

**CSS Only** - With a bit of a hack. You will need to generate in ID for each check box and associated label. In this instance the button **must** come before the table.

```css
/*Use CSS to hide the rows of the table that is next to check box that is next to an element with a class of tableToggle*/
.tableToggle + input[type="checkbox"]:checked + table>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}

/*Hide the checkbox*/
.tableToggle + input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}

/*Button Styling only -- noting important here*/
.tableToggle{
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:28px;
 border:1px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial; 
 padding:5px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<label class="tableToggle" for="cb1">Toggle Rows</label><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1 C1</td>
      <td>R1 C2</td>
      <td>R1 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2 C1</td>
      <td>R2 C2</td>
      <td>R2 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R3 C1</td>
      <td>R3 C2</td>
      <td>R3 C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Jon P nice answer, why do we need to have the button before the table? And how can we have the same result with the button after the table? Ty

Comment: @user9007028, not with the CSS only solution. With query use `next` instead of `prev`, for pure javascript use `nextElementSibling` instead of `previousElementSibling`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you decide to use a library like jQuery, this is going to require a decent amount of code. Abstracting out certain functionality like showing and hiding elements helps to reduce the bloat:

```js
function hide (e) { e.style.display = 'none' }

function show (e) { e.style.display = '' }

function additionalRows (table) {
  return [].slice.call(table.rows, +table.getAttribute('data-initial-rows'))
}

function insertAfter (e, reference) { 
  reference.parentNode[reference.nextSibling ? 'insertBefore' : 'appendChild'](e, reference.nextSibling)
}

function showAll () {
  additionalRows(this.previousSibling).forEach(show)
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
}

var template = document.createElement('button')
template.textContent = 'Show All'

document.querySelectorAll('.expandable-table').forEach(function (table) {
  additionalRows(table).forEach(hide)
  
  var button = template.cloneNode(true)
  button.addEventListener('click', showAll)
  insertAfter(button, table)
})
```

```html
<table class="expandable-table" data-initial-rows="10">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>X</th><th>Y</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tr><td>7.34</td><td>9.56</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5.64</td><td>4.14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0.99</td><td>8.55</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9.18</td><td>8.65</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6.60</td><td>3.25</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.88</td><td>5.29</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0.40</td><td>5.36</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9.74</td><td>7.14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7.61</td><td>6.32</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3.87</td><td>2.80</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0.77</td><td>0.11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.78</td><td>5.45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2.40</td><td>7.54</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6.53</td><td>1.45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7.92</td><td>1.90</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1.81</td><td>4.69</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9.40</td><td>7.86</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3.33</td><td>5.08</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0.18</td><td>3.16</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1.54</td><td>0.80</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This way :**

```js
 $('.btnShow').click(function () {
            $(this).prev("table").find("tr.expand").toggle();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Taylor</td>
                <td>123456789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="expand" style="display:none">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>456789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="expand" style="display:none">
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Mr. Patel</td>
                <td>456789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="expand" style="display:none">
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Nirav</td>
                <td>987654321</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Show / Hide" class="btnShow" />
```